# Is it possible to reverse-engineer a Botnet "Node", to find hard-coded values like the IP of a CnC Server?

Tags: reverse-engineering, hacking

I wondered if it's possible to reverse engineer a Botnet "Node" (aka the Client/Malware), to find hard-coded values, like the IP of the Command Server (CnC Server) to catch the Operator of the Botnet?

Like if there's some variable `let server = "some_ip_goes_here"` and it was compiled to an .EXE and you "de-compile" it?

Answer (score 2):

> it's possible to reverse engineer a Botnet "Node" (aka the Client/Malware), to find hard-coded values, like the IP of the Command Server (CnC Server) to catch the Operator of the Botnet?

Yes

> is it possible … if there's some variable let server = "some_ip_goes_here" and it was compiled to an .EXE and you "de-compile" it?

Yes

But it’s also possible to design a bot that doesn’t have the C&C IP address hard coded. A bot could be designed with a “don’t call us, we’ll call you” philosophy.

In such a situation no amount of decompiling will point you to the C&C servers. You’ll need to log it happening.

Comment: "A bot could be designed with a “don’t call us, we’ll call you” philosophy." - how would that work? How would the C&C server know about the bot node at all?

Comment: A simple strategy would be simply to broadcast a call to exactly the port that allowed the compromise in the first place, and wait for responses from infected nodes.

Comment: @KilianFoth correct. The drawback is a naïve implementation would make the C&C noisy. But if you have, say, a botnet, you can farm that work out.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, yes.

Practically, the people that write these things (or at least, the people that write the toolkits to generate these things) aren't dumb and know that people will try and decompile them, so they'll take all sorts of steps to make it really quite hard to extract this kind of information. Don't expect just to drop the executable into Ghidra and have the address pop out.